# Program closing abruptly when file doesn't exist (IOResult file handling)

Tags: pascal

I used IOResult to verify the existence of a file, when it exists everything works fine but when the file doesn't exist the program closes abruptly.

I tried to use a try - except to catch the exception but the problem persists, perhaps I'm not using the exception properly? But not sure how should I use it.

```
function verifyExistence(var input:text):boolean; 
var x:word; //IOResult
var r:boolean;
    begin
        try
            {$I-}
            reset(input);
            {$I+}
            x:=IOResult;    
        except on E: EInOutError do begin
            r:=false;
            exit;
        end;
        end;

            if (x <> 0) then
                r:=false //File does not exist
            else
                r:=true; //File exists
        close(input);
        verifyExistence:=r;
    end;
```

```
procedure fopen(var path:string);
var exists:boolean;
begin
    writeln('Specify file path. Example: C:\Users\Frank\Desktop\example.txt');
    readln(path);
    assign(input,path);
    exists:=verifyExistence(input);
        if exists then begin
            //writeln('File exists');
        end
        else begin
            writeln('File does not exist');
        end;
end;
```

Comment: have you tried using another signature of "reset" ? for example "reset ( var f:file )" instead of "reset ( var t:Text )" ?

Comment: You can't mix IOResult and exceptions. Use one or the other. They're incompatible. Turning on IOResult stops exceptions from being raised. What Pascal are you using?

Comment: @KenWhite I had it initially without the exception and I have the same issue though. I'm compiling using dev pascal 1.9.2

Comment: That may be, but adding the exception handler didn't do anything but clutter your code. Turning on IOResult will prevent any exception from being raised as a result, so you'll never get an exception from `reset()`. BTW, Dev Pascal uses FreePascal, which has a `FileExists` function. Why aren't you using that instead?

Comment: @KenWhite I didn't know about that, will try it out.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved the problem:

I removed the verifyExistence function, just left fopen like this:

```
procedure fopen(var path:string);
begin
    writeln('Specify file path. Example: C:\Users\Frank\Desktop\example.txt');
    readln(path);
    if not FileExists(path) then begin
        writeln('File does not exist'); 
        exit; 
    end;
    assign(input,path);
end;
```

Thanks for the help